# Jquery Ajax request Fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a web service that does work properly when asked directly by url but i cant seem to call it through a Jquery Ajax call.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery("#field1").focusout(function() {
    alert("focusOut");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/motifRes/name',
        data: { 'clRef' : document.getElementById("field1") },
        datatype: 'text',
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#nomClient").val(msg);
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

I do enter in the function because i get the "focusOut" alert but then nothing, just nothing. 
I used the Chrome developper tool and fiddler and I see no request, no error.

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

About your questions :

> are you requesting from an external domain? 
>   Blockquote

No I am not

> Are you sure its a POST request?

Well either way, it doesnt change a thing =/

Here's my HTML

```
                <div class="panel" id="standard">
                <form id="test" action="#" method="get">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Formulaire de changement du motif d'annulation</legend>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="field-label"><label for="field1">Ref Client</label>:</div>
                        <div class="field-widget"><input name="field1" id="field1" title="Entrer la référence client" /><input id="nomClient" readonly="readonly" type="text" value=""></input></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your html as well?

Comment: `work properly when asked directly by url` Are you sure its a POST request?

Comment: are you requesting from an external domain?

Comment: Install firebug in FF and check if there is any request going. if there is any paramteres posted and what is the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. A vicious and well rookie mistake I guess...

```
url: '/motifRes/name'
```

=!

```
url: 'motifRes/name'
```

The slash does mean an absolute path and without it the root of my webservice does concat with the url...

Answer (score 1):

Use done(), fail(), and always() instead of success() and error(). Also use document.getElementById("field1").value instead of document.getElementById("field1").

```
jQuery("#field1").focusout(function() {
    alert("focusOut");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/motifRes/name',
        data: { 'clRef' : document.getElementById("field1").value },
        datatype: 'text',
        done: function(msg) {
            $("#nomClient").val(msg);
        },
        fail: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
             alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @touti One fine morning, you will wake up and find that they have stopped working aka deprecated. "Deprecated, deprecated functions everywhere," is what you will say then :)

Comment: me gusta ! it doesnt fix my problem but thanks for the advice anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `data` attribute to

```
data: { 'clRef' : $("#field1").val() },
```

Comment: It did prevent Chrome from freezing the page for some weird reason.
But my problem remains

Comment: or  `document.getElementById("field1").value` ?

Comment: @ClydeLobo there is jQuery, so why dont use jQuery selectors?

Comment: @Hysael problem is in somewhere else. it should work. I tested before I posted the answer

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov : that was for the OP, he used js in that line of the example ;)

Comment: @ClydeLobo ah,ok. little misunderstanding :)